# Easily switch between multiple AWS accounts (in separate organizations) in the website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a personal AWS account, and I was also added as an IAM user on another organization's account to access their ec2 resources.

Is there an easier way to switch between these two accounts from the website https://console.aws.amazon.com/?

Right now, I have to go to the separate URLs for each of my accounts that are in the form https://78xxxxxxxxxxx.signin.aws.amazon.com/console

But is there a way to switch from inside the AWS console itself without having to bookmark those URLs and re-type in my password to switch between them?

It seems that AWS lets you switch between different roles very easily, but this doesn't seem to work across accounts? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-account-access-in-the-aws-management-console/

Comment: cross account role would work for your case, for the very first time you would need to enter account info and roleName. Later you can switch without entering info.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple accounts and they are inside the same organization, you can use SSO login to access multiple accounts without typing the password as long as you have the correct permission to access them.

In the AWS `IAM Identity Center(SSO)` you can assign the `permission sets` to different accounts,

And the left side the `Dashboard` section has the SSO URL `AWS access portal URL` which will show you the multiple accounts

Reference Links: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/useraccess.html

Answer (score -1):

If each of the accounts belong to separate AWS organizations, they'll have separate URLs. The cross-account role switching applies to multiple accounts under a single AWS organization.